# fullscreenactivity is not working could anyone fix it .

Tags: android, gridview, android-viewpager, onclicklistener, android-fullscreen

Its actually a imagegallery code that consist of gridlayout which shows the images stored in the SD card folder , and while clicking the grid images it will navigate to the another layout (full_screen) contains view pager shown below ,

```
FullScreenActivityjava


package com.example.imagegallery;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import com.example.imagegallery.R;
import com.example.imagegallery.image.adapter.FullScreenImageAdapter;
import com.example.imagegallery.image.help.*;


public class FullScreenViewActivity extends Activity{

    private Utils utils;
    private FullScreenImageAdapter adapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_screen);

        viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

        utils=new Utils(getApplicationContext());

        Intent i = getIntent();
        int position = i.getIntExtra("position", 0);
        adapter=new FullScreenImageAdapter(FullScreenViewActivity.this, utils.getFilePaths());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);

    }


}

>and here the Adapter for the above class

FullScreenImageAdapter.java
---------------------------

package com.example.imagegallery.image.adapter;
import com.example.imagegallery.image.help.TouchImageView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.example.imagegallery.R;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class FullScreenImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

     private Activity _activity;
        private ArrayList<String> _imagePaths;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

         public FullScreenImageAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<String> imagePaths) {
             this._activity=activity;
             this._imagePaths=imagePaths;
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        } 

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this._imagePaths.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return view==((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TouchImageView imgDisplay;
        Button btnClose;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View viewLayout =inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscreen, container,false);

        imgDisplay=(TouchImageView)viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
        btnClose=(Button)viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig= Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imagePaths.get(position), options);
        imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                _activity.finish();

            }
        });

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout);

        return viewLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

}


> here the grid adapter 

GridViewAdapt.java
------------------


package com.example.imagegallery.image.adapter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.imagegallery.FullScreenViewActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class GridViewAdapt extends BaseAdapter {

     private Activity _activity;
        private ArrayList<String> _filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
        private int imageWidth;

        public GridViewAdapt(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> filepaths,int imageWidth){
            this._activity=activity;
            this._filePaths=filepaths;
            this.imageWidth=imageWidth;
        }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return this._filePaths.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this._filePaths.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(_activity);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        // get screen dimensions
        Bitmap image = decodeFile(_filePaths.get(position), imageWidth,
                imageWidth);

        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(imageWidth,
                imageWidth));
        imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

        // image view click listener
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(position));
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return imageView;
    }

    class OnImageClickListener implements OnClickListener{
        int _position;

        public OnImageClickListener( int position)
        {
            this._position=position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(_activity,FullScreenViewActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("position", _position);
            _activity.startActivity(i);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

    private Bitmap decodeFile(String filepath, int WIDTH, int HIGHT) {
        try{
             File f = new File(filepath);

                BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

                final int REQUIRED_WIDTH = WIDTH;
                final int REQUIRED_HIGHT = HIGHT;
                int scale = 1;
                while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_WIDTH
                        && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_HIGHT)
                    scale *= 2;

                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o2.inSampleSize = scale;
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;
    }



}


> here the grid activity

GridViewActivity.java
---------------------

package com.example.imagegallery;
import com.example.imagegallery.image.help.*;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.imagegallery.image.adapter.GridViewAdapt;
import com.example.imagegallery.image.help.Utils;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class GridActivity extends Activity {

     private Utils utils;
        private ArrayList<String> imagePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
        private GridViewAdapt adapter;
        private GridView gridView;
        private int columnWidth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

        utils = new Utils(this);
        InitializGridLayout();

        imagePaths = utils.getFilePaths();
        adapter = new GridViewAdapt(GridActivity.this, imagePaths, columnWidth);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    private void InitializGridLayout() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         Resources r = getResources();
         float padding = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                 AppConstant.GRID_PADDING, r.getDisplayMetrics());

         columnWidth = (int) ((utils.getScreenWidth() - ((AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS + 1) * padding)) / AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS);

         gridView.setNumColumns(AppConstant.NUM_OF_COLUMNS);
         gridView.setColumnWidth(columnWidth);
         gridView.setStretchMode(GridView.NO_STRETCH);
         gridView.setPadding((int) padding, (int) padding, (int) padding,
                 (int) padding);
         gridView.setHorizontalSpacing((int) padding);
         gridView.setVerticalSpacing((int) padding);

    }




}
```

> the XML for full screen

```
Full_Screen.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


</LinearLayout>



Layout_Fullscreen.java

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.example.imagegallery.image.help.TouchImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imgDisplay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <Button 
       android:id="@+id/btnClose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="Close" />

</RelativeLayout>``
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid);
```